# Error 500 caused by java.lang.NullPointerException at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) when starting AEM local

Tags: aem

when trying to start the AEM local instance I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500 Server Error
URI:    /
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    Server Error
SERVLET:    org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet-58b30d2f
CAUSED BY:  java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.authenticate(JcrResourceProvider.java:304)
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.authenticate(JcrResourceProvider.java:76)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.stateful.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:161)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.stateful.ProviderManager.getOrCreateProvider(ProviderManager.java:87)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.stateful.ProviderManager.authenticateAll(ProviderManager.java:129)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.createControl(ResourceResolverImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.<init>(ResourceResolverImpl.java:103)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.<init>(ResourceResolverImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.CommonResourceResolverFactoryImpl.getResourceResolverInternal(CommonResourceResolverFactoryImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.CommonResourceResolverFactoryImpl.getResourceResolver(CommonResourceResolverFactoryImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverFactoryImpl.getResourceResolver(ResourceResolverFactoryImpl.java:98)
    at org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator.getResolver(SlingAuthenticator.java:799)
    at org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator.doHandleSecurity(SlingAuthenticator.java:514)
    at org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator.handleSecurity(SlingAuthenticator.java:460)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingHttpContext.handleSecurity(SlingHttpContext.java:134)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.PerBundleServletContextImpl.handleSecurity(PerBundleServletContextImpl.java:82)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:58)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher$1.doFilter(Dispatcher.java:146)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1002)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:326)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:136)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:136)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager.invokePreprocessors(WhiteboardManager.java:1012)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:91)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It was all correctly working last time I've used it; after the last launch I'm always getting this error when trying to start the instance.
All the bundles are correctly active.
I have jdk1.8.0_301.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Which version of AEM do you use?

Comment: In my eyes: remove this instance from file system and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

More likely this is a corrupted instance after an abrupt shutdown, it is better to create a new one.